# Is adding data on behalf of the original author fine?

Tags: discussion, editing

Q: [Entropy on native memorable password on macosX keychain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177911/entropy-on-native-memorable-password-on-macosx-keychain/)

The [author of the question](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/168803/alex-recuenco) seems to be happy with my answer, yet she or he [added some calculations](https://security.stackexchange.com/revisions/177911/3) based on my answer to his question and then [removed those](https://security.stackexchange.com/revisions/177911/5). Is it okay to add the removed data to [the answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/178158/168418)?

I've done that already, but I can revert that version if it's against the community policies.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the author tried to add it to your answer and it got rejected by the community because it had no context.

In general, collaborating on posts is fine as long as everyone is ok with it. Clear communication is key!